# Make select field toggle another field using Django Forms WITHOUT jQuery

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

How can I create a toggling behavior using Django form fields such as shown in the gif purely using Django? In the example below the user is prompted to choose only a Division or Center, if the division is chosen, center will automatically be prompted to None and vice versa.
[image: Desired field behavior]

In order to create the effect shown, I am using jQuery and some beginner Django code:

```
<div class="col-md-5">
            <label>Division </label>
            <select id="division" name="division" class="form-control select2">
              {%for division, name in divisions%}
              <option value="{{ division }}">{{ name }}</option>
              {% endfor %}
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <h3><strong>OR</strong></h3>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <label>Center</label>
            <select id="center" name="center" class="form-control select2">
              {%for center, name in centers%}
              <option value="{{ center }}">{{ name }}</option>
              {% endfor %}
            </select>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Set option selected onchange
    $("#center").change(function () {
      // Set selected
      if ($("#division").val() != "None" && $("#center").val() != "None") {
        $("#division").val("None");
        $("#division").select2().trigger("change");
      }
      return;
    });
    $("#division").change(function () {
      // Set selected
      if ($("#division").val() != "None" && $("#center").val() != "None") {
        $("#center").val("None");
        $("#center").select2().trigger("change");
      }
      return;
    });
  });
```

However the rest of my fields are declared using django forms:

```
class NewTitlesForm07(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NewTitlesForm07, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['start_month'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=MONTH_CHOICES, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'select2 form-control'}))
        self.fields['start_year'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=YEAR_CHOICES_07, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'select2 form-control'}))
        self.fields['end_month'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=MONTH_CHOICES, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'select2 form-control'}))
        self.fields['end_month'].help_text = '**Please note that the end date is the last day of the month.'
        self.fields['end_year'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=YEAR_CHOICES_07, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'select2 form-control'}))
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are using is a front-end and Django is basically a back-end. Sure, you do use Django and jinja2 to render the template but for a feature like this, it is better to use javascript or jquery. Even if you want to use Django, it will become a complex way and still, javascript/jquery will be required (for on click functionality) to send the form data again and again to the back-end and then based on conditions you can render the different forms. It won't be an efficient way of doing so.